# Global Timestamp variable returns null value when used in multiple java methods

Tags: java, jpql

I am experiencing a weird situation where a local timestamp variable works perfectly and returns the correct first value of an ArrayList in test method A. Now, I want to use that variable in a test method B, so I turned the variable into a global variable, declared at the class level. Strangely, the first value returned from the ArrayList id test method B is null, Clearly, the problem is with the second method not correctly reading the variable. The first method reads it OK. I am not sure what I have done wrong. This is what I tried:

```
private static Timestamp s; //variable declared globally
private static final TestDao TEST_DAO = new TestDao();

// 1st test method
  @Test
    public void testById() {
    List<TestEntity> tests = TEST_DAO.findById("");
    List<Timestamp> myDate = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TestEntity test: tests) {
    myDate.add(test.getDateColumn());//A list element added to the array
    }
      
    s = myDate.get(0); //Gets the first element from the list
    System.out.println("The first element is " + s); //The variable s successfully returns the first element of the array


//2nd test method
  @Test
    public void verifyMe() {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().plus(Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
    Date nowPlusOneeMinutes = Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
      
    System.out.println("The first element is " + s); //s returns a null value here even though it's declared as private static as class level

    }
```

Comment: In your first "working" test you never use your static class variable. You instead introduce a new local variable `Timestamp s = myDate.get(0);` and use that local variable. So that test has nothing to do with your field `private static Timestamp s;`

Comment: And you should not have a static variable that keeps state between tests, test have to be independent of each other.

Comment: In your second test the variable `s` is not initialised. A test never should rely on the execution of other tests to pass, think of each of them independently.

Comment: I have used `s = myDate.get(0);`, using the global variable and method A still works ok. Do you why it's not working in method B

Comment: @ Luis Iñesta, so how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Java doesn't have the concept of "Global variables"

```
private static Timestamp s; //variable declared globally
private static final TestDao TEST_DAO = new TestDao();

// 1st test method
  @Test
    public void testById() {
    List<TestEntity> tests = TEST_DAO.findById("");
    List<Timestamp> myDate = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TestEntity test: tests) {
    myDate.add(test.getDateColumn());//A list element added to the array
    }
      
    Timestamp s = myDate.get(0); //Gets the first element from the list
    System.out.println("The first element is " + s); //The variable s successfully returns the first element of the array
}
```

Yes, you do have an instant variable of the name s, but the variable you set, is local to your test method. It only exists within the scope of that test, and doesn't alter the s that can be reached by the other test.

Even if, maybe now it is different, but it's not certain the tests execute in the order you want them to.
If you want that value to be set right before each test, add this:

```
@Before
public void init() {
List<TestEntity> tests = TEST_DAO.findById("");
        List<Timestamp> myDate = new ArrayList<>();
    
        for (TestEntity test: tests) {
        myDate.add(test.getDateColumn());//A list element added to the array
        }
          
        s = myDate.get(0); // this will actually set the value of the s on instance level
}
```

This way, you have the element in both tests, yet the test are not dependent of each other.